# how can i store data for my android app so that when someone login from different device he can see his data can firebase be used

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-storage

i am making an app using kotlin. this app is like a diary for user where they can write about the day how can i store the data so that even if user uninstall it or open the app in different device they can see there data. can i use firebase for that do i have to pay for i only have very few users.

i want to store the data of my app user so that it doesn't get lost can i use some api or something to do so i dont want to pay for any service as it is only for very few users(experiment purpose). please tell where can i find an api which will be helpful in this case.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,
You need to define which server you will use to store user data (Firebase, Personal server.. etc).

Then you had multiple choices to ***SYNC*** user data with the server

**Synchronization Service**

You can use the power of [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager#features)

to do the job for you. By storing every new diary object inside RoomDB by inserting it to the DB and after successful insertion you can **SYNC** your data with your server using WorkManager and delete the diary object after successful update.

***OR***

You can insert every single diary in RoomDB as a ***list of diaries*** after saving it, and while the app is launching you can SYNC this list of diaries with your server.